# Solving for the constants of a cubic function where its graph is tangent to the x-axis at x=3

Tags: functions, factoring, cubics, tangent-line

$$x^3-4x^2+ax+b$$

I am unsure of my understanding of theory yet, but from what I do understand I assume that y=0 when x=3 because the graph is tangent to the x-axis at that point. With that amount of information what can I do to find the real constants a and b?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The body of a question should be understandable even by somoene who desn't read the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution without derivatives.

We need that $3$ would be a root of degree two.

Thus, $$3^3-4\cdot3^2+3a+b=0,$$ which gives
$$b=9-3a$$ and we obtain:
$$x^3-4x^2+ax+9-3a=0$$ or
$$x^3-4x^2+9+a(x-3)=0$$ or
$$x^3-3x^2-x^2+3x-3x+9+a(x-3)=0$$ or
$$(x-3)(x^2-x-3+a)=0,$$ which gives
$$3^2-3-3+a=0,$$ $$a=-3$$ and $$b=18.$$

Comment: Thank you for this perspective, it's really useful to be aware of different methods.

Comment: @Alkahest You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If $p(x)=x^3-4x^2+ax+b$, you want to have $p(3)=0$ and $p'(3)=0$. But$$p(3)=0\iff27-36+3a+b=0$$and$$p'(3)=0\iff27-24+a=0.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Never thought about getting the derivative, so I really appreciate the insight, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.